# Fast converting decimal to binary numbers - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert about 33'000'000 decimal numbers to binary.
At the moment I'm working with this script:

```
$top = 33000000000
$binary
$out
$cache
for($i = 0; $i -lt $top; $i++){
$binary = [Convert]::ToString($i, 2)
$cache = $binary
$out = 10000000000000000000000000 + $cache
Write-Host $out
$out | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\inffhe\Desktop\binary\binary.txt -Append
} 
Read-Host
```

Well it works, but its far to slow...
With this speed, it would be running about 5 days straight.
Do you have any idea how to make ths faster?
I'm adding "10000000000000000000000000" to the number, because it needs to have 25 digits.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: note that [decimal] is NOT [int]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove any console output, e.g. `Write-Host`.
2. `$out = 10000000000000000000000000 + $cache` implicitly converts your binary string back into an integer (or maybe even `double`) to perform the addition. Make sure your numbers have the 25th bit set initially, e.g. with `$i -bor 0x100000`.
3. Use a different language. C# would likely be no less readable and way faster than PowerShell.

On my machine here the following snippet executes in a bit under 7 seconds:

```
0..100000|%{[Convert]::ToString(($_-bor0x1000000), 2)}|out-file x.txt
```

which means the full 33000000 numbers would be somewhere around 40 minutes.

On the other hand, the following C#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class X{
  static void Main() {
    using (var f = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("x.txt"))) {
    for (int i=0;i<33000000;i++) {
      f.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i | 0x100000, 2));
    }
    }
  }
}
```

executes in just a few seconds. For all 33000000 numbers. Generating an 820 MiB file.

Comment: Good suggestions, though C# may not be much faster depending on what methods are being used (especially true in v3+). If PowerShell is needed but only C# performs well enough, it's also possible to embed the C# with `Add-Type`.

Comment: @briantist, sure, `Add-Type` is an option. Although I'm often faster with just writing a short C# file and running it through csc. Editing C# code in a PowerShell string is also kinda awkward most of the time. And for things like loops C# is *way* faster than PowerShell, because it's not interpreted. Their main issue here is most likely the conversion from `int` to `string`, back to `int`, and then to `string` again, though. That sort of thing is never fast.

Comment: @Joey all good points, I would only add that PowerShell 3+ using the DLR helped with performance a lot, and I think that would be most evident in a loop. [PowerShell 3 Finally on the DLR!](https://dzone.com/articles/powershell-3-finally-dlr) & [PowerShell Performance: It's the DLR](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/donjones/archive/2012/05/07/powershell-performance-it-s-the-dlr.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This finished in a little over a minute:

```
filter convert {[convert]::ToString($_,2)}
$pad = [convert]::ToInt32('10000000000000000000000000',2)
$top = 33e6
($pad..($top + $pad)) | convert
```